# SQL and Counting

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate-functions

I have a table which consists of the following

```
Student Name        Grade       Class
--------------------------------------------------------
User 1              A           English
User 1              B           Math
User 2              B           Math
```

I'm trying to create a query where it will list all students, total *pass* grades (grades A,B & C), total A's, Total B's, Total C's

Can someone help me create the query or atleast put me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you looking only for the Total for each grade?

Comment: @ShaikhFarooque: Yes just total number of instances for pass grades and all passgrades together for EACH student

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
select name,
    count(case when grade in ('A', 'B', 'C') then 1 end) totalPass,
    count(case when grade = 'A' then 1 end) totalA,
    count(case when grade = 'B' then 1 end) totalB,
    count(case when grade = 'C' then 1 end) totalC
from t
group by name
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44634/1).

Or we can make it even simpler if you were using MySQL:

```
select name,
    sum(grade in ('A', 'B', 'C')) totalPass,
    sum(grade = 'A') totalA,
    sum(grade = 'B') totalB,
    sum(grade = 'C') totalC
from t
group by name
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/658a5/1).

Comment: Although this is what I'm looking for, this wont work in MS Access (Sorry I should have mentioned that earlier)

Comment: Have you got an alternative that will work in MS Access?
CASE statements dont work in Access

Comment: @Imran I use linux and I don't have access. Try replacing the comparisons in the `sum` solution with [iif function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php). Something like: `iif(grade = 'A', 1, 0)`

Answer (score 3):

You should use `sum` instead of `count`, and use a conditional expression inside, like this:

```
select
  sum(case when grade in ('A','B','C') then 1 else 0 end) as passing
, sum(case when grade = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as NumA
, sum(case when grade = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as NumB
, sum(case when grade = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as NumC
from grades
```

This example is for SQL Server [(see sqlfiddle here)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a82af/5), but other RDBMSs have similar capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another possible answer (very long but self explanatory):

```
select u.UserName 
,totalA = count(a.Grade) 
,totalB = count(b.Grade) 
,totalC = count(c.Grade) 
,totalPass = count(p.Grade) 
from
GradeUser u
LEFT JOIN GradeUser a on a.UserName = u.UserName
 AND a.Grade = u.Grade AND a.Class = u.Class
 AND a.Grade ='A'
LEFT JOIN GradeUser b on b.UserName = u.UserName
 AND b.Grade = u.Grade AND b.Class = u.Class
 AND b.Grade ='B'
LEFT JOIN GradeUser c on c.UserName = u.UserName
 AND c.Grade = u.Grade AND c.Class = u.Class
 AND c.Grade ='C'
LEFT JOIN GradeUser p on p.UserName = u.UserName
 AND p.Grade = u.Grade AND p.Class = u.Class
 AND p.Grade IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
GROUP BY u.UserName
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in Access SQL, in two separate queries:

Number of total pass grades per student:

```
SELECT grades.StudentName, Count(grades.Grade) AS NumberOfPassGrades
FROM grades
WHERE (((grades.Grade) In ('A','B','C')))
GROUP BY grades.StudentName
ORDER BY grades.StudentName;
```

Number of total A's, Total B's, Total C's:

```
SELECT grades.StudentName, grades.Grade, Count(grades.Grade) AS NumberOfGrades
FROM grades
GROUP BY grades.StudentName, grades.Grade
ORDER BY grades.StudentName, grades.Grade;
```

If you really need only **one** query, the easiest way to do this would be to save both queries as Access queries and join them on StudentName. However, then you would get the NumberOfPassGrades more than once as soon as a student has more than one different grade.

Comment: The number of total pass grades query works and is what I'm
However the second query shows each grade, what I'm trying to implement is where it will display each user and the sum'ed grade in a column.
Mosty Mostacho got it right but the only problem is I believe CASE statements dont work in MS Access

Comment: @Imran: are you saying that you don't want each grade in the second query, but only a sum of all grades instead? This sounds exactly like the first query to me...or I don't understand what you want to do.