# Grades display in java and sql

Tags: java, sql

I have sql table as shown

```
Name  |eng    |kisw
Jane  |A      |B
Ann   |B      |B
Mag   |B      |B
```

I need to calculate grades like `Eng A=1` `B=2` and `Kisw B=3`

I have sql code but displays wrong data

```
SELECT name,COUNT(eng),COUNT(kisw) FROM form1 GROUP BY eng ,kisw
```

Comment: what do u mean by calculation here? sum?

Comment: How A would be 3? It should be 1 right?

Comment: Please be more specific in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, this would help:

```
SELECT 'ENG' as SUBJECT, ENG AS GRADE, COUNT(ENG) AS GRADE_COUNT FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY ENG
UNION
SELECT 'KISW' AS SUBJECT, KISW AS GRADE, COUNT(KISW) AS GRADE_COUNT FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY KISW
```

Output is :

```
ENG     |A   |1
ENG     |B   |2
KISW    |B   |3
```

To run Test query use:

```
WITH TEST_DATA AS
(
SELECT 'JANE' NAME, 'A' ENG, 'B' KISW FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'ANN' NAME, 'B' ENG, 'B' KISW FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'MAG' NAME, 'B' ENG, 'B' KISW FROM DUAL

)

SELECT 'ENG' SUBJECT, ENG GRADE, COUNT(ENG) GRADE_COUNT FROM TEST_DATA GROUP BY ENG
UNION
SELECT 'KISW' SUBJECT, KISW GRADE, COUNT(KISW) GRADE_COUNT FROM TEST_DATA GROUP BY KISW
```

Comment: Thanxs alot for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Try this is it will help

```
select name,
    sum(eng = 'A') totalA,
    sum(eng= 'B') totalB,
    sum(eng = 'C') totalC
from student
group by name
```

for more details visit this

- [SQL and Counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240035/sql-and-counting)
- [sql - getting the count of employee in each grade in a specific
  format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287658/sql-getting-the-count-of-employee-in-each-grade-in-a-specific-format)